# How to get specific value from ArrayList in POJO in java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, pojo

```
Key : 22 Value: Abey
Key : 22 Value : Dawn
Key : 22 Value : Sherry
Key : 22 Value : Sherry
Key : 22 Value : Sherry
```

I want to print only Keys with Sherry only,how to do  it using Java?

Changing title of question because HashMap doesn't store duplicate Keys

Comment: Show what you have attempted so far, this is not an spoon feeding website

Comment: I have one EndPoint through that end point i'm getting response and i stored that response in one java class and after that i stored in one list as it involves many child node then in that list i have above key and value pair , i want to get Value "Sherry" only

Answer (score 1):

HashMap doesn't accept duplicate keys. Only duplicate values. In your approach you can't be able to store all the records as you are showing.
for example:

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(22, "Abey");
map.put(22, "Dawn");
map.put(22, "Sherry");
map.put(22, "Sherry");
map.put(22, "Sherry");
```

when you print the output of the HashMap. You only get one output because the same key will replace to latest value.

output:

```
{22=Sherry}
```

If you really want to store duplicate keys, Learn more about how to store duplicate keys in HashMap.

Comment: i think i can go with Array List

Comment: ArrayList doesn't support key-value pair. If you need a key-value pair, HashMap is the better option here.

Comment: Yeah u r right but  i have one json response which is stored in java object and i'm able to iterate through that response as list and able to print all the keys and value but not only specific value

Comment: You need to create a list of name object and assign the same key for that name list. Map<Integer, List<Name>> something like this. Try to learn about adding list of object against same key in hashmap. You will find the perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below method from JDK1.8 and above to complete the task.

```
List<Integer> keys = hashMap.entrySet().stream()
            .filter((entry) -> entry.getValue().equals("Sherry"))
            .map(entry -> entry.getKey())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: thanks for the answer , your approach is right  but  i need to do with Array List

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to loop through the map. There is no specific function to do this

```
map.forEach((k,val) -> {
  if (val.equals("Sherry") {
    keys.add(k);
  }
});
```

where map is the HashMap and keys is a list

Comment: I'm using Java 8

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tushar but i need to use Array List in this case

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code.

```
static < K, V > List < K > getAllKeysForValue(Map < K, V > mapOfWords, V value) {
    List < K > listOfKeys = null;
    //Check if Map contains the given value
    if (mapOfWords.containsValue(value)) {
        // Create an Empty List
        listOfKeys = new ArrayList < > ();
        // Iterate over each entry of map using entrySet
        for (Map.Entry < K, V > entry: mapOfWords.entrySet()) {
            // Check if value matches with given value
            if (entry.getValue().equals(value)) {
                // Store the key from entry to the list
                listOfKeys.add(entry.getKey());
            }
        }
    }
    // Return the list of keys whose value matches with given value.
    return listOfKeys;
}
```

Comment: i tried this but it's replacing all keys with same Value

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the reverse map , having Sherry , Dawn and Abey as keys , and 22 as the value of list. 
You can have something like :

```
Map<String , Set<String> > reverseMap;
```

Now you can store the *keys like 22* in the set and have the key of this map as the name.